# Best way to update a HTML table in real time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, postgresql

**Background Info**

I have a html table with some data in it. The first data row should always be highlighted. Basically the table consists of two important colums. One is `Title` and the other column of the table is `Votes`. The table should be ordered in by this column (descending, most votes on top). This info was just for better understanding and is pretty irreleveant, since I'm already ordering the data on the backend.

---

Now to the question. The table is on a site without user interaction, it is just for a presentation. The data in the table is changed by another site and is stored in a Postgres database. I'm searching for a good way to update this table. Currently I'm doing this by generating the code with PHP and refresh the page all 5s with

```
setTimeout(function() {
     window.reload(1);
}, 5000);
```

I don't think this is a good solution, since as said, the site is for a presentation and it doesn't look very good if the site loads for a few milliseconds all the time.

My idea would be to periodically send a ajax request, get the new data (as JSON) and update the table. I guess I have to create an API for this. Currently the table also has a fixed size of 8 rows.

Do I have to completely remove all rows and insert the rows again or are there some good ways to achieve this in JS? Would it be possible to determine if the database has changed and only send data in this case? Just wanted to get some expertise, before I'm investing to much time in this.

Comment: I would check out https://datatables.net/ to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: maybe u could look at Websockets ?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Websockets are nice, but wouldn't that be a bit overkill? I don't need a bi-directional connection

Comment: @IanFako With Web Sockets you would get real live updates, but if it just should be accurate at a few seconds i would also recommend using AJAX requests.

Comment: I second DataTables, it's really great for HTML tables with a server-side data source. https://www.datatables.net

Answer (score 1):

You should use websockets to build right live application. If you dont want to start from scratch use some library like pusher.
https://pusher.com/docs/libraries

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the jQuery ajax stuff and your 5 Seconds

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "vote_table.php",
        data: {
            method: "easy_call"
        },
        success: function(content) {
            $("#table").text(content);
        }
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: can you explain what you are doing?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are right at the thought of using AJAX and creating a API as it would not be good for user experience to load the whole page everytime.

And, creating an API is good as it will reduce the data size as compared to HTML.

In my opinion you should just check for updates in database and fetch data only when updated, so it will reduce the data size in frequent request.

And for creating and updating the table, I would suggest you to use [jQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/). As it is a already configured library which will ease the table handling for you and will provide basic tools.

Hope it would help.